# zipfile module very slow when zip the previously unzipped files

Tags: python, windows, python-zipfile

I have a code to make zip files out of a folder.

```
import os
import zipfile
import time

def zip_folder(input_folder, output_folder, max_files_per_zip):
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Initialize variables
    current_zip_num = 1
    current_zip_file = None
    file_count = 0

    # Traverse the input folder and zip the files
    start_time = time.time()
    for root, _, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file_count += 1

            # Create a new zip file if necessary
            if file_count > max_files_per_zip or current_zip_file is None:
                if current_zip_file:
                    current_zip_file.close()
                    duration = time.time() - start_time
                    print(f"Zip file {current_zip_num-1} created in {duration:.2f} seconds.")
                current_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(
                    os.path.join(output_folder, f"archive{current_zip_num}.zip"), "w"
                )
                current_zip_num += 1
                file_count = 1
                start_time = time.time()

            # Add the file to the current zip file
            current_zip_file.write(file_path, os.path.relpath(file_path, input_folder))

    # Close the last zip file
    if current_zip_file:
        current_zip_file.close()
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        print(f"Zip file {current_zip_num} created in {duration:.2f} seconds.")

    print("Folder A has been successfully converted to zip files in folder B.")
```

where

```
# Usage example
input_folder = "path/to/folder_A"
output_folder = "path/to/folder_B"
max_files_per_zip = 1500

# Zip folder A into multiple zip files in folder B
zip_folder(input_folder, output_folder, max_files_per_zip)
```

Each zip file contain 1500 files. However, something strange happened. If a zipfile module previously "zipped" the files in `folder_A/subfolder_01` then zip `folder_A/subfolder_01` again was very fast, i.e. 5s. However, if the files in `folder_A/subfolder_02` was not previously "zipped" by the zipfile module, it was very slow, i.e. 80s. This was not because of the system IO, since each zip file was around 500 MB and the hardrive has an IO speed of over 200 MB/s.

Is this a bug? How to make the zipfile module aware of the files in the folders as it has previoulsy zipped the files?